# Suppress output of variables substitution in sqlplus

Tags: sql, variables, sqlplus, oracle-ebs

I'd like to suppress the output of such lines as the following ones

```
old   9: AND FROMDAT <= TO_DATE('&duedate', 'YYYYMMDD')
new   9: AND FROMDAT <= TO_DATE('20091031', 'YYYYMMDD')
old  10: AND TODAT > TO_DATE('&duedate', 'YYYYMMDD')
new  10: AND TODAT > TO_DATE('20091031', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

How could I achieve this?

`TERM OFF` and `FEEDBACK OFF` is already set.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`SET VERIFY OFF` is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

SET VERIFY OFF does suppress the parameter substitution dialogue, but it does not prevent the parameter entry (Enter value for..) chatter from being written to output.

However if you combine that with SET HEADING OFF you will have output that includes only return data with no garbage at the top.

I use this when I need to have a sqlplus program return XML output to an Oracle concurrent request.